# Django: If I start a table, and then have a {% block %}{% endblock %} and close the table after, does it break the table?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, html-email

I am making an html email template, and the header and footer for various email templates are on a single page that is included on each email. They are set up in tables, and the header and footer are contained in a single table. Because I am providing the body of the email in a separate file, it has to be broken up with a block.

Apple mail renders the tfoot wrong, as if the footer is separate from the rest of the table. Is this because it is broken up by the block tags? How can I make it work, if so?

This is the barebones setup for reference.

```
<body>
  <table>
    <th>
      ----
    </th>

    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
       <td>
        -----
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: This depends on what is inside this block. When browser renders HTML there are no Django tags already so they cannot affect anything.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed to know.